# Aggregate and get all fields

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I can now do something like this:

```
{
    "$match": {
        "$and": [
            {
                "$or": [
                    { "to": system.mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId) },
                    { "from": system.mongoose.Types.ObjectId(userId) }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
},
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$conversationId",
        "from": { "$first": "$from" },
        "to": { "$first": "$to" },
        "content": { "$first": "$content" },
        "createDate": {"$first": "$createDate"}
    }
}
```

And get just first result for each `conversationId` but how can I get all records?

Comment: what is meaning of eche ?

Comment: Inside `conversation` I need to get all messages not just first one.

Comment: use $push instead of $first  https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/push/

Comment: If I use `$push` how can I populate then?

Comment: Why do you group by id if you need all records? Show the output that you want to get

Comment: Becouse I need all records but grouped by conversationId

Comment: Instead of populate you can use **$lookup** which is MongoDB's feature. And if you want to get all records not first the just write **"from": { "$push": "$from" }** instead  **"from": { "$first": "$from" }**